# https version of website being redirected to some random website

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, website

My website `http://www.scoredragon.com/`, when accessed with `https` i.e `(https://www.scoredragon.com/)` instead of `http` is being redirected to `book-your-driving-test-online.co.uk`. I have searched for the past 2 days for the code that redirects the website but my efforts were futile. Can any body tell me how I can stop this redirect.
Thanks in advance. Cheers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk to your hosting provider (Hostgator India?). While you own your domain name, presumably you share the IP address 119.18.47.216 with other domains. It's up to the hosting provider to ensure the sharing doesn't cause problems.

Comment: I will try that right away!!

Comment: @jaisonDavis Yep, the hosting provider is serving the other web site, even with their SSL certificate. You need to talk to them.

Comment: but the http site is pointing to the right place

Comment: its just the https that is being redirected

Comment: @jaisonDavis: What's your point?